# AJAX and PHP - Two Different Errors Depending on Use of JSON dataType

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, postgresql

I'm trying to bring my web skills into the 21st century by learning AJAX and PHP but have hit a wall.  I want to populate a select control "recipe" with options depending on what was chosen from an initial select control "category".  The option items for the secondary control "recipe" will be the parsed results from an AJAX query executed against a PostgreSQL database table.  The function "makeAjaxRequestCategory" shown in the code below is a jQuery AJAX call which includes the property dataType: 'json'.  This is where the problem is.  Best I can figure, the problem comes when I include that property and let the code run, which, instead of returning something with results I can parse, returns as an error... BUT the response object also indicates status 200 (which is "OK"... so why is it being interpreted as an error?).  The responseText property of the response object includes the following:

```
responseText:"<br />↵<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in <b>C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.38-0\apache2\htdocs\ajaxSelectCategory.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />↵
```

When I remark-out the dataType property and run it without, I get a different error:

```
jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '179' in <br />(…)
```

It seems like the proper way to do this is to set dataType to JSON and then parse the JSON object that I get back from PHP but instead I seem to be getting a contradictory response, both an error and a response of 200 at the same time. Note that the initial PHP call to populate the "category" control works fine. Any guidance you can give on getting a successful response that I can parse would be most appreciated!

Here's my development environment:

- Local development with "localhost" on a Windows 10 laptop
- Apache web server v. 2.4.23 (Win32)
- PostgreSQL version 9.6.1
- Running it in Chrome and using Chrome's DevTools for troubleshooting

Here's the main file 'recipesystem.php' that I run in the browser:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>

Version 317.0<br><br>

<div class = 'selection'>
<table id='selectiontable'>
  <tr>
    <td>Select Recipe Category</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="category">
      <option value='Select a category...'></option>
      <?php
        $connection = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=recipes user=postgres password=XXXXXXXX");
        $result = pg_query($connection,"SELECT category FROM recipesystem.recipe ORDER BY category;");
        while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          unset($category);
          $category = $row['category'];
          echo '<option value="'.$category.'">'.$category.'</option>';
        };
      ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>

<select id="recipe">
<option value='Select a recipe...'></option>
</select>

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
  // This is for the Category selector...
  $('#category').on('change', function(){
    $('#recipe').empty();
    var selected = $(this).val();
    makeAjaxRequestCategory(selected);
    })
  function makeAjaxRequestCategory(opts){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: { opts: opts },
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'ajaxSelectCategory.php',
      success: function(res) {
        console.log("Success...")
        console.log(res)
        $.each(res, function(i, value) {
          console.log(value)
         })
        },
      error: function(res){
        console.log("There was an error...")
        console.log(res)
        }
    })
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

ajaxSelectCategory.php

```
<?php
    echo "<script> console.log('Starting PHP script....');</script>";
    $connection = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=recipes user=postgres password=XXXXXXXX") or die("Connection Error");
    $result = pg_query($connection,"SELECT name, category FROM recipesystem.recipe ORDER BY category;");
    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "$('#recipe').append('<option>newvalue</option>');"
    };
?>
```

Comment: you are sending html not json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very happy to move from old centuries,
You should change ajaxSelectCategory.php to seem like this:

```
<?php
    echo "<script> console.log('Starting PHP script....');</script>";
    $connection = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=recipes user=postgres password=XXXXXXXX") or die("Connection Error");
    $result = pg_query($connection,"SELECT name, category FROM recipesystem.recipe ORDER BY category;");
$output=array();
    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output[] = $row['field name'];
    };
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

And your success callback to :

```
success: function(res) {
        console.log("Success...")
        console.log(res)
        $.each(res, function(i, value) {
          $('<option>'+value+'</option>').appendTo($('#recipe'));
         })
        },
```

Comment: The initial echo in my ajaxSelectCategory.php script was creating a badly formed JSON response, but once I removed that and incorporated your suggestion it started working correctly.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first the HTTP code is 200 OK, which means a request was send followed by a response. Code 200 does not guarantee that the body of the response hasn't got any errors, basically because the HTTP request is handled by Apache and the error you see is created by the execution of your code with PHP. If things weren't that abstract, every language that wanted to handle HTTP requests would implement different codes and that isn't really responsibility of a language.

Second, when you define `dataType: 'json'` on your ajax request, you're telling "Hey, I want to RECEIVE json formatted data", since youre ajaxSelectCategory.php script does not echoes json formatted data, you're getting an error from the browser because the JSON parser does not understand what you're receiving, it's set to decode JSON but it's not encoded as JSON.

So either `dataType: 'html'`, and treat `res` as a whole string with HTML code, or you make an array with results and echo the `json_encode()` of it, only then you'll be able to iterate through it as you want to in `$.each(res, function(i, value) {`